# Converting existing JSON field in PostgreSQL to use in PostGIS

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I currently have a postgres database in which I store a data about a photo, along with the location as a JSON (using Django). The location is obtained through GooglePlacesAPI-
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search (search for Search Responses for example responses)

So currently, every photo has a `location` column which contains the JSON information for the place as obtained from the GooglePlacesAPI

Now I would like to use Postgres' spatial capabilities to query based on the location, however I am not sure how to do that and what schema changes are required. The Postgres documentation seems to indicate that there would be a new table required with the location's name, lat, lng and other information. So does that mean that every location will be saved in a different table and will have a foreign key referenced to that?
And so the JSON will need to be essentially flattened to be stored in the table?

If so, is there a recommended table format that would be good to store the location in so that I can get any other location data (say from Foursquare, FB, etc) and convert it to the format of the table before storing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometry is not special: it's just another data type. So add a geometry column to your existing table. Assuming you have installed and enabled PostGIS 2.x:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point,4326);
```

Then populate the geometry data by extracting the data out of the `location` JSON column (which really depends on how the data are structured within this amorphous column):

```
UPDATE mytable SET
  geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint((location->>'lng')::numeric,
                                 (location->>'lat')::numeric), 4326)
```

And that should be a start. Later steps would be to build GiST indices and do spatial queries with other tables or points of interests. You may also want to consider the `geography` data type, instead of the `geometry` data type, depending on your needs.